# Regex not properly matching the restricted values

Tags: java, regex

I have created a regex to check if email address has admin, firmware,services & repair. If I put'ad' instead of 'admin' in email address then also it returns true which is not correct as per the requirement.

```
private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN_New =
            "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[admin|firmware|repair|service]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

static String email = "xxxx@admin.com";
static String email1 = "xxxx@ad.com";
static String email2 = "test@irm.jdsu.com";
public static boolean validate(final String hex) {
        pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN_New);
        matcher = pattern.matcher(hex);
        return matcher.matches();   
    }
System.out.println(validate(email));     //true
System.out.println(validate(email1));     //true  but it should be false
System.out.println(validate(email2));    //true  but it should be false
```

same with other email address firmware, services, repair.

Comment: Replace `[admin|firmware|repair|service]+` with `(admin|firmware|repair|service)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew static String email2 = "test@irm.jdsu.com"; returns true even if I replace + with – as suggested. Rather it should be false.

Comment: [Look here](https://regex101.com/r/iZ6uT2/3). It should not match the regex. And [this is a Java demo](https://ideone.com/MbbE1A)

Comment: Bravo Man, demo works. But I am still trying to figure out where i was wrong in regex, I have removed -  but still in some cases it works other it doesn't. Your regex works for almost all cases I have tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `[admin|firmware|repair|service]+` with `(admin|firmware|repair|service)`.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iZ6uT2/1)

The `[admin|firmware|repair|service]+` is a character class matching separate characters, `a`, `d`, etc. one or more times (due to `+`). So, it will match `ad`, `add`, `fir`, etc.

The `(admin|firmware|repair|service)` is a *sequence grouping* construct, matching either `admin`, or  `firmware`, etc.

Note that you can shorten the regex in Java by replacing `[_a-zA-Z0-9]` with `\w`:

```
private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN_New = "^[\\w+-]+(?:\\.[\\w-]+)*@(?:admin|firmware|repair|service)(?:\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}$";
```

And you can even drop the `^` and `$` since you are using the regex with the `matches()` method.

[Java demo from IDEONE](https://ideone.com/MbbE1A):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN_New =
            "^[\\w+-]+(?:\\.[\\w-]+)*@(?:admin|firmware|repair|service)(?:\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}$";

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String email = "xxxx@admin.com";
        String email1 = "xxxx@ad.com";
        String email2 = "test@irm.jdsu.com";

        System.out.println(email.matches(EMAIL_PATTERN_New));     // true
        System.out.println(email1.matches(EMAIL_PATTERN_New));    // false
        System.out.println(email2.matches(EMAIL_PATTERN_New));    // false
    }
}
```